# AngularJS problems with $http GET

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I built web service with php that reads a database and `echo` json. I go to the path to see the result and the result is success. Here an example of my web service.

```
[{"id":"1","skill":"1","src":"walmart","total":"1"},{"id":"1","skill":"1","src":"target","total":"2"}]
```

Here is my app.js code

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app =   angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
app.controller('DeveloperTable', function ($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;

        // GET request example:
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../_includes/web_service_person.php'
        }).then(function successCallback(data) {
            vm.developer = data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log(":(");
        });
    });

})();
```

Here is my index.html

```
<div ng-controller="DeveloperTable">
    <h4>Developer Assesment</h4>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>pid</th>
          <th ng-repeat="(skill, value) in developer | groupBy: 'skill'">
            {{skill}}
          </th>
        </tr>
```

The funny part is that I don't have errors in my console, but I'm not getting data either.
What I'm missing here?

**Edit**: The `groupBy` filter comes from the [angular-filter library](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

Comment: what output are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `ng-controller="DeveloperTable as vm"` and then iterate `vm.developer`

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-repeat` syntax is: `ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"`.  Based on the json you posted, `vm.developer` is an array, so `skill` would be set as the array index.

I am also not so sure about that `groupBy: 'did'`, because I don't see any `did` property in your json objects.

Try it like:

```
<th ng-repeat="data in vm.developer | groupBy: 'id'">
    {{data.skill}}
</th>
```

Comment: I'm using [this dependency](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) therefore the syntax si slightly different.

Comment: GroupBy: 'did' was a typo. I update my question. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: haha, well dependencies like that should definitely be mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

You need to do `$scope.developer = ...` in your code, `vm.developer` is not in your scope on the page.

That aside, you can:

Open Firebug in your browser, go to the network tab and look at the HTTP request to your web service.  You can see if it returns data.  If it does, debug it like:

Look at your HTML, and add `<pre>{{developer | json}}</pre>` and I think you'll see that it's empty.

Comment: Either `$scope.developer = ...;` to not expose entire controller on scope.  OR  `ng-controller="DeveloperTable as vm"` to expose controller on scope as `vm`

Comment: I did both, `<pre>{{developer | json}}</pre>` and opened the `dev tools, network, response` and my json object is there.

Comment: so the `<pre>{{developer | json}}</pre>` is rendering your object now?  how about `<pre>{{developer | groupBy: 'skill' | json}}</pre>` ?